# what is the role of $watch service?

Tags: angularjs

i have a below code in which i want to change UI View using Ng-switch based on $scope value change.

but for me it works normally then what is the use of $watch

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
$scope.count = 0;
$scope.counter = function(){
$scope.count += 1;
};

$scope.$watch('count',function(){
     console.log('a');
});

$interval($scope.counter,'10000');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ firstName + " " + lastName }}<br/><br/>

{{count}}


<div ng-switch="count">
<div ng-switch-when="1">div 1 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="2">div 2 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="3">div 3 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="4">div 4 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="5">div 5 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="6">div 6 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="7">div 7 called</div>
<div ng-switch-when="8">div 8 called</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the $watch here is just there for debugging... The former dev must have used `console.log` to check that the code was working.

Comment: I first thought just counter increase will not change View part ... but it changes ... my question is if $scope value is detected normally and reflected in view then in which scenario i should use $watch service ... i am confused with this ... plz explain this in eg if possible

Comment: $watch simply allow you to "watch" for change in a scope variable and do something if so. But this is often not clever to use it because it can involve a lot of calls to the function you defined. Typically, you use it when you don't control who or what changed the value. Prefer using a function call when the user changes the variable in a form for example. I think you should read that page : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Answer (score 0):

It appears your *$watch* block is logging out if the $scope.count has changed. You've got 4 things going on:

1. You're setting name values on the scope.
2. You've got a function that is incrementing $scope.count.
3. You're displaying different div's based on what the $scope.count value is.
4. You're logging to the console what your $scope.count number is via your $watch whenever that value changes.

It seems your $watch is entirely for debugging.

Comment: I first thought just counter increase will not change View part ... but it changes ... my question is if $scope value is detected normally and reflected in view then in which scenario i should use $watch service ... i am confused with this ... plz explain this in eg if possible